# How do I recycle a character vector in R?

Tags: r

I have a list of every day from `2018-01-01` to `2018-06-01`. It is a vector and it looks like this:

```
dates <- c("2018-01-01", "2018-01-02", "2018-01-03", ... , "2018-05-30", "2018-06-01")
```

I want to make a data frame where the first column has each of those dates and the second column has their day of the week. I am assuming that `2018-01-01` is a Monday.

```
date           day
2018-01-01     Monday
2018-01-02     Tuesday
2018-01-03     Wednesday
...            ...
2018-06-01     Monday
```

I'm working on a data frame towards that end, but I was curious for a better way to recycle through the days of the week than the solution I put together.

```
day <- NULL
for (i in 1:length(dates)) {
    x <- i
    while (x > 7) {
        x <- i - 7
    }
    day <- c(day, days[x])
}

cbind(dates,day)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `weekdays` to get day of the week and put it in a dataframe.

```
data.frame(dates, day = weekdays(dates))

#      dates       day
#1 2018-01-01    Monday
#2 2018-01-02   Tuesday
#3 2018-01-03 Wednesday
#4 2018-05-30 Wednesday
#5 2018-06-01    Friday
```

**EDIT**

If we don't want to use any in-built function we can create a vector of days and lookup from there. Considering the first day is "Monday" we can use the modulo operator to find the relevant day for rest of the `dates`

```
days <- c("Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday")

day <- days[(as.numeric(dates - dates[1]) %% 7) + 1]
day
#[1] "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Wednesday" "Friday"
```

and then put them in dataframe

```
data.frame(dates, day)
#       dates       day
#1 2018-01-01    Monday
#2 2018-01-02   Tuesday
#3 2018-01-03 Wednesday
#4 2018-05-30 Wednesday
#5 2018-06-01    Friday
```

**data**

```
dates<-as.Date(c("2018-01-01","2018-01-02","2018-01-03","2018-05-30","2018-06-01"))
```

Comment: For reasons related to the project, I'm not allowed to use any 'magic functions'

Comment: I'm limited to just 'dplyr' and base packages.

Comment: @Cauder I have updated the answer. I hope this does not fall into your category of "magic function". `weekdays` is a base function.

Comment: Beautiful, that's perfect. Thanks Ronak!

Comment: Is %% called integer division?

Comment: it's called modulo operator, it gives the remainder after division. Try `12 %% 7`, `12 %% 6`.